# Same method on different array types in Go

Tags: go

I've seen some similar questions ([How can two different types implement the same method in golang using interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31505587/how-can-two-different-types-implement-the-same-method-in-golang-using-interfaces)), but in my case my types do not have the same base type. My types are arrays of different sizes.

```
type Ten [10]byte
type Twenty [20]byte

func (t *Ten) GetByte0() byte {
    return t[0]
}

func (t *Twenty) GetByte0() byte {
    return t[0]
}
```

So, it's possible don't to repeat the two methods GetByte0()?

Comment: If you have two separate types and you want them to behave the same way you need to define that behaviour for both of them.

Comment: I think reflection is the only way you can have one function do that for two different types, and it's probably not worth it. The way you've written it is the normal way to do something like that.

Comment: Can you use a slice instead of arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Ten [10]byte

type Twenty [20]byte

type Number []byte

func (n Number) GetByte(i int) byte {
    return n[i]
}

func main() {
    t10 := Ten{10}
    fmt.Println(t10)
    n10 := Number(t10[:])
    fmt.Println(n10.GetByte(0))

    t20 := Twenty{10, 20}
    fmt.Println(t20)
    fmt.Println(Number(t20[:]).GetByte(1))
}
```

Output:

```
[10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
10
[10 20 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
20
```