# Same method on different types and return different type value in Go

Tags: go

I've seen some similar question([Same method on different array types in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43700989/same-method-on-different-array-types-in-go))

But in my case my functions do not return same types.

Can you write the below code more simply?

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
)

type A struct {
  Name string `json:"name"`
  Age  int    `json:"age"`
}

type B struct {
  Name    string `json:"name"`
  Age     int    `json:"age"`
  Address string `json:address`
}

func UnmarshalA(b []byte) *A {
  var t *A
  _ = json.Unmarshal(b, &t)
  return t
}

func UnmarshalB(b []byte) *B {
  var t *B
  _ = json.Unmarshal(b, &t)
  return t
}

func main() {
  a := []byte(`{"name": "aaaa", "age": 1}`)
  unmarshal_a := UnmarshalA(a)
  fmt.Println(unmarshal_a.Name)

  b := []byte(`{"name": "bbbb", "age": 2, "address": "b@example.com"}`)
  unmarshal_b := UnmarshalB(b)
  fmt.Println(unmarshal_b.Name)
}

// aaaa
// bbbb
```

https://play.golang.org/p/PF0UgkbSvk

Comment: It is simple already.

Comment: I think it seems repetition has occured in functions UnmarshalA and UnmarshalB.

Comment: I know it is not the answer you were looking for but it seems simpler to me to not have the `UnmarshalA` and `UnmarshalB` functions at all: https://play.golang.org/p/7zY9MW1JpC

Comment: Why do you have a method wrapping such a simple operation anyway? I hope this is just a simplified example... but I fear it may have simplified away the important bit. This feels a lot like an XY problem to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

1. Don't bother using `UnmarshalA` and `UnmarshalB`.
   They're really not doing much and you're really only abstracting away a single line... `var t *A`
2. If you don't actually need the `A` and `B` structs and simply want the contents of the JSON string represented in a way you can use it, you could just unmarshal into a `map[string]interface{}`.

E.g.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func UnmarshalAny(b []byte) map[string]interface{} {
    var t = make(map[string]interface{})
    _ = json.Unmarshal(b, &t)
    return t
}

func main() {
    a := []byte(`{"name": "aaaa", "age": 1}`)
    unmarshal_a := UnmarshalAny(a)

    b := []byte(`{"name": "bbbb", "age": 2, "address": "b@example.com"}`)
    unmarshal_b := UnmarshalAny(b)

    // Accessed like this...
    fmt.Println(unmarshal_a["name"])
    fmt.Println(unmarshal_b["name"])
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/KaxBlNsCDR

If you wanted to pass the data by reference then you would change it to something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func UnmarshalAny(b []byte) *map[string]interface{} {
    var t = make(map[string]interface{})
    _ = json.Unmarshal(b, &t)
    return &t
}

func main() {
    a := []byte(`{"name": "aaaa", "age": 1}`)
    unmarshal_a := UnmarshalAny(a)

    b := []byte(`{"name": "bbbb", "age": 2, "address": "b@example.com"}`)
    unmarshal_b := UnmarshalAny(b)

    // Accessed like this...
    fmt.Println((*unmarshal_a)["name"])
    fmt.Println((*unmarshal_b)["name"])
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/AXKYCCMJQU

Comment: If I need the A and B structs, my code is correct?
Or anything else are able to write simply code?

Comment: I may need generics or `go generate`, though I am not sure.

Comment: If you need the A and B structs, refer to `1. ` in my answer. I'm not sure generics will do anything to help you either as that sort of thing would come into play after the structs have been instantiated. Plus I don't think `go` even supports generics at this time.